# how to uninstall any other OS without uninstalling Lubuntu

Tags: uninstall, bootloader, mint

i have installed 2 OS on my computer. Linux Mint and Lubuntu 13.04 ( No windows )
now how do i uninstall Linux Mint ? 
keeping in mind i've no windows OS so no bootloader issue i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think just format the drive or partition Mint is installed on. after that install [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer) and remove the Linux mint entries from your grub list. If you want to add the disc space of the mint install to the Lubuntu install you will be able to do so wit gparted, but you should do it from a live cd/usb because you need to unmount the Lubuntu partition